# Rails, simple pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a `Photo` model of which the first photo that belongs to a certain model shows up in like a modal window, in this case these are photos for recipes. My question is this, how can I know which photo is *next* in the set of all the photos?

```
def show
  @photo = Photo.find params[:id]
  # @next_photo = ?
  # @previous_photo = ?
end
```

How can I know which photo of the collection I'm looking at? The photo is actually derived from `@recipe.photos` in the view for the modal, but how can sort of know which one is next and previous? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using something like [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/) that will do all this for you? You could then just set the `per_page` to be 1.

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
@recipe_photos = @photo.recipe.photos
@next_photo = @recipe_photos[(@recipe_photos.index @photo) +1]
```